# Autocreated events from gmail don't block schedule

Tags: gmail, google-calendar

I have been using the **Bookable Appointments** feature in **Google Calendar**. This is very convenient since it lets my contacts choose when to have a meeting.

However there is one problem I noticed: some events on my calendar are auto-created by Google using say an email on Gmail regarding a flight etc.

Those events don't automatically show up as "busy" on the calendar and can result in double booking the same slot.

Any fix or workaround for it?

Edit: I have a personal Google account but pay for additional storage and Google One. Hence the booking page perk.

Comment: I expect this is by design. These events exist separate from your other events and can be toggled on and off see [Manage your events from Gmail](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6084018). How important is this to you? Do you want to script a solution? Can you just modify the events yourself? Are you willing to use a separate calendar for appointments that can have those events synced programmatically from the main calendar and switched to busy?

Comment: @Blindspots Thank you! It is a fairly important feature for me. A script would work. So would the last option. Everything other than manual modification. I presume you mean copying events to a regular calender manually?

Comment: @Blindspots done!

Comment: TY. Let me circle back

Comment: Nother annoying thing i discovered: I can hide visibility so it doesn't clutter my calender. But there is no way to do this on the App? It's annoying to have a booking schedule show up every day of my calender in the Android app.

Comment: Please [edit] relevant info into the question don't put it in the comments. When you edit please include a screenshot of both scenarios so it is clear what you mean.